# Query last unt price before with detail record

Tags: sql, sql-server

#### sample

```
+---------+------------+----------+------------+
| prdt_no | order_date | quantity | unit_price |
+---------+------------+----------+------------+
| A001    | 2020-01-01 |      100 |         10 |
| A001    | 2020-01-10 |      200 |         10 |
| A001    | 2020-02-01 |      100 |         20 |
| A001    | 2020-02-05 |      100 |         20 |
| A001    | 2020-02-07 |      100 |         20 |
| A001    | 2020-02-10 |      100 |         15 |
| A002    | 2020-01-01 |      100 |         10 |
| A002    | 2020-01-10 |      200 |         10 |
| A002    | 2020-02-01 |      100 |         20 |
| A002    | 2020-02-05 |      100 |         20 |
| A002    | 2020-02-07 |      100 |         20 |
| A002    | 2020-02-10 |      100 |         15 |
+---------+------------+----------+------------+
```

#### expected

if query condition is `order_date between 2020-02-02 and 2020-02-10` then the data will be expected to get below result

```
+---------+------------+----------+------------+------------------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------------------+
| prdt_no | order_date | quantity | unit_price | last_unit_price_before | unit_price_diff | cost_reduce | last_unit_price_change_date |
+---------+------------+----------+------------+------------------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------------------+
| A001    | 2020-02-05 |      100 |         20 |                     10 |              10 |        1000 | 2020-02-01                  |
| A001    | 2020-02-07 |      100 |         20 |                     10 |              10 |        1000 | 2020-02-01                  |
| A001    | 2020-02-10 |      100 |         15 |                     20 |              -5 |        -500 | 2020-02-10                  |
| A002    | 2020-02-05 |      100 |         20 |                     10 |              10 |        1000 | 2020-02-01                  |
| A002    | 2020-02-07 |      100 |         20 |                     10 |              10 |        1000 | 2020-02-01                  |
| A002    | 2020-02-10 |      100 |         15 |                     20 |              -5 |        -500 | 2020-02-10                  |
+---------+------------+----------+------------+------------------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------------------+
```

#### logic

- I hope to get same product last unit price before then use it to calculate the price difference
- the data record count actually over 200K

like photo
[image]

#### test demo link

[SQL Server 2012 | db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=b07ae7db064ad2ace10bdbf3533679ca)

Comment: Why do you have 20s in the column?

Comment: @GordonLinoff 2020-XX-XX ? it's taiwn date format. like `XX/XX/2020`

Comment: . . The column `last_unit_price_before`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff e.g A001 on 2020-02-10 price is 15 but the price last one is 20 on 2020-02-07

Comment: why `2020-02-01` is not in the result ?

Comment: also what is the formula for `cost_reduce ` ?

Comment: @Squirrel  thanks , i update answer to fix it, and the format is decimal `###,###.##`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `OUTER APPLY()` to get the last low with price difference

```
SELECT *,
       unit_price_diff = T.[unit_price] - L.[last_unit_price_before]
FROM   T
       OUTER APPLY
       (
           SELECT TOP 1 
                  last_unit_price_before = x.[unit_price],
                  last_unit_price_change_date = x.[order_date]
           FROM   T x
           WHERE  x.[prdt_no] = T.[prdt_no]
           AND    x.[order_date] < T.[order_date]
           AND    x.[unit_price] <> T.[unit_price]
           ORDER BY x.[order_date] DESC
       ) L
WHERE  T.[order_date] >= '2020-02-01'
AND    T.[order_date] <= '2020-02-10'
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=7c4d48c391b03f8fb6cdeb17fe280c9f)

Comment: I didn't include the `cost_reduce` as i am unsure of the calculation